# First hammer candle of the day

Tags: pine-script

I would like to be notified/mark on the first 15 min hammer candle of the day. Could someone help me with the pine script for this. I am only interested in the first hammer candle and not every hammer candle in the day.

Here is the code:

```
//@version=3
study("Hammer Scanner", overlay=true)

//input variables
//input variables
hammerBodyHeight = input(title="Hammer Body, Max Height (Pips)",type=integer,minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=300,confirm=false)

shadow = input(title="Body, Max Proportion of Tail (Fraction)", type=float,minval=0.01,maxval=1.0, step=0.01, defval=0.33, confirm=false)
tail = input(title="Shadow, Max Proportion of Body (Fraction)", type=float,minval=0.01,maxval=1.0, step=0.01, defval=0.5, confirm=false)
//scanner algorithms
hammer = (abs(close - open) / syminfo.mintick <= hammerBodyHeight) and (close > open) and ((close - open) < (open - low) * shadow) and ((high - close) <= (close - open) * tail)

//chart plotters
plotshape(hammer, style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color=green, text='Hammer')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can identify the hammer but multiple hammers are being marked..how can I write a condition to avoid the following candles after 1 is identified...

Comment: Could you please share your code that identifies the hammers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can use the `dayofweek` built-in variable to figure out if it is a new day. Then use a variable to keep track of it you have found a hammer and reset this variable on a new day.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Hammer Scanner", overlay=true)

//input variables
//input variables
hammerBodyHeight = input.int(title="Hammer Body, Max Height (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=300,confirm=false)

shadow = input.float(title="Body, Max Proportion of Tail (Fraction)", minval=0.01,maxval=1.0, step=0.01, defval=0.33, confirm=false)
tail = input.float(title="Shadow, Max Proportion of Body (Fraction)", minval=0.01,maxval=1.0, step=0.01, defval=0.5, confirm=false)

bool newDay = dayofweek[1] != dayofweek
var hammerFound = false
hammerFound := newDay ? false : hammerFound // Reset hammerFound on a new day, keep its value otherwise

//scanner algorithms
hammer = not hammerFound and ((math.abs(close - open) / syminfo.mintick <= hammerBodyHeight) and (close > open) and ((close - open) < (open - low) * shadow) and ((high - close) <= (close - open) * tail))

if (hammer)
    hammerFound := true

//chart plotters
plotshape(hammer, style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, text='Hammer')
```

[image]